# Uniform convergence of piece-wise function

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying the convergence of the sequence of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by:

$$f_n(x) = 0 \text {     if    } x<0$$
$$f_n(x) = nx \text { if } 0\leq x \leq 1/n$$
$$f_n(x) = 1 \text { if } x>1/n.$$

I have determined the pointwise limit to be $f(x) = 0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $1$ otherwise.

I am now asked to study the uniform convergence of the sequence. Is my reasing right here?

$(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $(-\infty,0]$ since given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N>0$ so that for $n\geq N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |0-0| = 0 <\epsilon$.

$(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly on any interval like $(-a,b)$ where $a,b>0$ since each $f_n$ is continuous but the limit function $f$ is not.

Lastly, the convergence is uniform on $[a,\infty), a>0$ since given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N$ such that $1/N<a$ and so for $n\geq N$ and $x\in[a,\infty)$we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |1-1| = 0<\epsilon$.

Comment: For your last statement are you assuming $a >0$?

Comment: @ArcticChar, yes --- thanks I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The $f_n$ are continuous but the limit function $f$ is not - so the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: I am interested in studying the convergence on the seperate intervals not on the reals

Comment: @math1000 are my statements correct?